# How to select only tags which does not have a specific tag inside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, queryselector

I want to be able to use `querySelectorAll` to query all `i` elements which does not have a `font` tag inside of it. I have tried the following selector, but it is not working:

```js
  document.querySelectorAll('i > *:not(font)')
```

```html
<i>
   <font color="008000">Here goes some text</font>
</i>
<br />
<i>Here goes another text</i>
```

Comment: The [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) is deprecated, and should not be used (that’s not exactly relevant to your problem, or question, though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in question doesn't select all `i` elements which do not contain a `font` element like you intend. It actually selects all children of `i` that are not `font` elements.

```js
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll('i>*:not(font)')])
```

```html
<i>
  <font color="008000">Here goes some text</font>
</i>
<br />
<i>Here goes another text</i>
```

For the behaviour you want, you'll need to use the new `:has()` selector in CSS which is [available in all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-has) (except behind a flag in firefox):

```js
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll('i:not(:has(> font))')])
```

```html
<i>
  <font color="008000">Here goes some text</font>
</i>
<br />
<i>Here goes another text</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('i:not(:has(font))');
```

It should work.

Comment: Doesn't work in firefox without enabling a flag (feb 2023)

Answer (score 0):

Because you're spreading the NodeList that `querySelectorAll()` returns into an array with `[...]`, we can just use array standard methods to remove DOM nodes from it:

```js
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll("i")]
  .filter((el) => !el.querySelector("font"));
  
console.log(elements);
```

```html
<i><font color="008000">Here goes some text</font></i>
<br>
<i>Select me!</i>
<i>And <b>me too</b>!</i>
<i>However, <span><font>I am doubly nested, don't select me</font></span></i>
```

Comment: Sorry I added that code when editing the question, didn't realise it added an issue